# VS2012 Project as DLL to be use in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm new to Windows Environment Programming esp Visual Studio.
I've one doubt.
I'm going to work on a project which has been developed under VS2012. It's dependencies all are resolved under VS2012.
Using this project as dll, I have to create a plugin using Google Sketchup C++ SDK. After understanding Sketchup c++ SDK, i came to know, it's SKpWriter APIs libs were build using VS2005 [SKP C++ SDK](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/downloadsdksubmit) 

 Now my doubt is, If I want to use dll which was built using VS2012/VS2010, how can i use it under VS2005. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Create an according DLL project using VS2005, but don't add any files to it. Then, add the existing source code to it, set up the compiler settings and you should be going. It works to have multiple project files in one directory, just add according suffixes to denote the VS version. If you set up paths accordingly, you can even have the same project in different VS versions at the same time, to check if you didn't break anything for the other environment. BTW: Your question is a bit vague, if you have more specific problems, ask more specific questions.

There is one problem though: If the DLL has a C++ interface as opposed to a more basic C interface, you are out of luck, because you generally can't mix output from different compilers.